# Click inner div run fancybox, how to stop bubble to outer div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

How can I make if click .a(bluearea) then .menu fadein,
but click .apic(apic is inside a) run fancybox and menu not fadein?

http://jsfiddle.net/e5Tdv/12/

jQuery

```
$('.apic').fancybox({});
$('.a').not('.apic').click(function(){
    $('.menu').fadeIn();
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="a">
    <a class="apic" rel="gallery" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg">
        <img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" alt=""/>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="menu">menu</div>
```

CSS

```
.menu{
    display: none;
}
.a{
    background: blue;
}​
```

Comment: did you create your own function `notfadeIn()`? ... because that is not a valid jQuery method. What you were trying to do with such `notfadeIn` ?

Comment: No I don't know how to create function notfadeIn, sorry just example what i trying to do.

Comment: I tried $('.apic').click(function(e){ 
  e.stopPropagation()
 }); but not working and also fancybox not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check where user clicked (event target) and fade when not clicked on image, for example:

```
$('.apic').fancybox({});

$('.a').click(function(e){
    $('.menu').hide(); // This is just to see that it works

    if ($(e.target).is('div')) {
        $('.menu').fadeIn();
    }
})
```

​

See in action - http://jsfiddle.net/Qeay5/